# Mocking a TempData in ASP.NET Core in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, mstest

```
public ActionResult View(string name)
{
    if (TempData["SessionVariable"] != null)
    {
        FileName = name;  
        return View();
    }
    else
    {  
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }

}
```

TestMethod

```
public void UseCaseView_CorrectRequirements()
{
    var mock = new Mock<Controller>();
    mock.Setup(p => p.TempData["SessionVariable"]).Returns("admin");
    Controller.View("SAMPLE.xml");           
}
```

It throws an error such as ,

Result StackTrace:

> at Moq.Mock.ThrowIfSetupExpressionInvolvesUnsupportedMember(Expression
>   setup, MethodInfo method) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 883 
>   at Moq.Mock.SetupGetPexProtected[T,TProperty](Mock`1 mock,
>   Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) in
>   C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 537    at
>   Moq.Mock.SetupGet[T,TProperty](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression,
>   Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 517    at
>   Moq.Mock.SetupPexProtected[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1
>   expression, Condition condition) in
>   C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 507    at
>   Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression,
>   Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 484    at
>   Moq.QueryableMockExtensions.FluentMock[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock,
>   Expression`1 setup) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Linq\Mocks.cs:line 224 
>   at lambda_method(Closure )    at Moq.Mock.GetTargetMock(Expression
>   fluentExpression, Mock mock) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line
>   856    at Moq.Mock.SetupPexProtected[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock,
>   Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) in
>   C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 505    at
>   Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression,
>   Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 484    at
>   SE_WEBAPP.Tests.TestControllers.UsecaseControllerTests.UseCaseView_CorrectRequirements()
>   in
>
> > D:\Public\SE_WEBAPP_TESTCASE\SE_WEBAPP\SE_WEBAPP.Tests\TestControllers\UsecaseControllerTests.cs:line 23
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>   SE_WEBAPP.Tests.TestControllers.UsecaseControllerTests.UseCaseView_CorrectRequirements
>   threw exception:  System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a
>   non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: mock => mock.TempData

Comment: You can check this url how we can mock temp data https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/mvc-unit-testing-controller-actions-that-use-tempdata

Comment: I am using .net core framework and MStest for core framework , The given is .net 4.7.1 framework. This mismatching for me. i check it . Thanks and any more suggesstion please.@RakeshKumar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In asp.net-core, `Controller.TempData` is a public property, so you can easily access it and set the desired key/value

```
public void UseCaseView_CorrectRequirements() {
    // Arrange
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    tempData["SessionVariable"] = "admin";        
    var controller = new UsecaseController() {
        TempData = tempData
    };
    var expected = "SAMPLE.xml";

    //Act
    var view = controller.View(expected) as ViewResult;
    var actual = controller.FileName;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much@Nkosi

Comment: For NSubstitute mocking library the line will be ` 
   var tempData=  new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Substitute.For<ITempDataProvider>());`

Comment: Works a treat. Good answer.

Comment: TempDataDictionary does not contains constructor that receive 2 arguments

Comment: @Toshihiko What version of the framework are you using? This answer is for the .net core version which does have a constructor that takes 2 arguments https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/TempDataDictionary.cs,28 while the previous version ( aspnet-mvc-5.2) did not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2