# Dealing with TempData variables in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, tempdata

Following the example from here:

[Mocking a TempData in ASP.NET Core in MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181767/mocking-a-tempdata-in-asp-net-core-in-mstest),

I wrote down the following TestMethod:

```
[Fact]
public void TestBackMethod()
{
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    tempData["id"] = 3008;
    var controller = new PhaseController(Configuration)
    {
        TempData = tempData
    }; 
    var result = controller.Back() as ViewResult;
    Assert.Contains("Index", result.ViewName);
}
```

For this Controller Method:

```
public IActionResult Back()
{
    int releaseId = (int)TempData["id"];
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Phase", new { id = releaseId });
}
```

However, on this line:

```
Assert.Contains("Index", result.ViewName);
```

`result` is `null`.

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Back` doesn't return a `ViewResult` - it returns a `RedirectToActionResult` (you can hover over RedirectToAction to see the exact object name). Both of these implement `IActionResult`.

You get a Null Reference Exception because when you use the `as` keyword for casting objects it will return null if the conversion is not possible.

If you instead had

```
var result = (ViewResult)controller.Back();
```

You would get a difference exception during run time of that line saying the conversion was not possible.

You should do the conversion doing one of these methods:

```
var result = (RedirectToActionResult)controller.Back();
```

or

```
var result = controller.Back() as RedirectToActionResult;
```

Comment: Oh, so it wasn't because of the `TempData`! Thanks a lot for the help, it's working perfectly now.