# DefaultHttpContext testing authentication in integration tests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Trying to run some integration tests and using DefaultHttpContext in my unit and integration tests. Is there a way to call **SignInAsync()** on DefaultHttpContext?

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        await _controller.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
```

Running above throws an **exception when using DefaultHttpContext** for some reason:

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198341/how-to-unit-test-httpcontext-signinasync) may helpful.

Comment: yep, that worked. thanks much. @Yingiu please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can either create a fake/mock manually by creating classes that derive from the used interfaces or use a mocking framework like `Moq`.

Referenced with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198341/how-to-unit-test-httpcontext-signinasync).