# MSTest: Unit Testing HttpContext.SignoutAsync for the logout

Tags: mstest, httpcontext

Simply passing Mock HttpContext to the controller context while unit testing logout functionality will throw following error
**HttpContext.Signout + value can not be null (Parameter 'provider')**

```
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
```

//set the controller HttpContext

```
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object;
```

// Now call the Logout action method and Test result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drill down to the definition of SigOutAsync code it expect Authentication Service Provider which should not be null .
Hence , along with mocking HttpContext you also need to mock the service provider which will solve the issue .

```
       //mock the Http Context along with Service provider
        var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        var authServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
        authServiceMock.Setup(_ => _.SignOutAsync(It.IsAny<HttpContext>(), It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<AuthenticationProperties>())).Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));
        var serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
        serviceProviderMock.Setup(_ => _.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationService)))
            .Returns(authServiceMock.Object);
        mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.RequestServices)
          .Returns(serviceProviderMock.Object);

        //set the controller HttpContext
        _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object;
       // Now call the Logout and Test
```

Similar logic can be applied while testing SignIn functionality

Refer here as well- [How to unit test HttpContext.SignInAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198341/how-to-unit-test-httpcontext-signinasync)